# Explode Hyphens in breadcrumbs

Tags: php, html, css, breadcrumbs

I have this script that does nearly exactly what I would like it to do but I need to remove the hyphens.

It produces the breadcrumbs using the pages of my website but I need it to do this

```
Home > Aaa bbb ccc > Aaa bbb
```

instead of

```
Home > Aaa-bbb-ccc > Aaa-bbb
```

I know I need to use the PHP explode() function but I cannot seem to figure out where the put it.

```
<?php
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' > ', $home = 'Home') {

$path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
$base_url = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], '/')) . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
$breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base_url\">$home</a>");
$tmp = array_keys($path);
$last = end($tmp);
unset($tmp);

foreach ($path as $x => $crumb) {
$title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), array('', ' '), $crumb));
if ($x == 1){
$breadcrumbs[]  = "<a href=\"$base_url$crumb\">$title</a>";
}elseif ($x > 1 && $x < $last){
$tmp = "<a href=\"$base_url";
for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++){
$tmp .= $path[$i] . '/';
}
$tmp .= "\">$title</a>";
$breadcrumbs[] = $tmp;
unset($tmp);
}else{
$breadcrumbs[] = "$title";
}
}

return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}
echo breadcrumbs();

?>
```

Comment: `$title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_', '-'), array('', ' ', ' '), $crumb));`

Comment: OK, I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand what you have to:

```
$title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_', '-'), array('', ' ', ' '), $crumb));
```